# How Can I Avoid Writing an Assignment Operator for my Immutable Class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, immutability, operator-keyword, assignment-operator

I have written an immutable class Coords, with only two members - const int x and const int y. However, the compiler wants me to write an assignment operator, which, from what I can gather, makes no sense for an immutable type. Here's an example:

```
//location is a Coords* and Coords::DOWN is a static const Coords&.   
Coords& next = Coords(location);
next = next + Coords::DOWN;
```

Intellisense does not like the use of "=" in line 3. I figure that the issue is that I've already allocated memory for 'next', so when I want to replace the stuff in that memory with something else, it does not like that. Am I correct? How can I get around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If your type is "immutable", how exactly would you expect this *mutating* operation to work?

Comment: `Coords(location)` creates a temporary (you have a dangling reference), and you don't re-assign to a reference, you assign to referenced `Coords` object.

Comment: "*Intellisense does not like the use of '=' in line 3.*" It shouldn't like line 2 either, but that's a longstanding VC++ compiler bug that they're unlikely to fix.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter on that last comment and now it won't let me edit. I meant to say:
I don't want a muting operation, I want next to be set to the result of next + Coords::DOWN. Replaced, not modified. I kind of get that this is what pointers are for? But if I made next a pointer, then "next = next + Coords::DOWN would cause a memory leak, right? I am not very good at this. Sorry to have bothered everyone.

I made a few edits so as to improve the code:
//location is a Coords* and Coords::DOWN is a static const Coords&.   
Coords next(location);
next = next + Coords::DOWN;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want 'next' to be reference-to-Coords. You want it to be an object of type Coords. Try this:

```
Coords next = *location + Coords::DOWN
```

The destructor for 'next' will be called by the run time when 'next' goes out of scope (often at the end of the method)

You will want to write a + (plus operator) override in any event. (Your object is not immutable. You need to read up on that).